# How to Drag and Drop a text file in new tab using swing

Tags: java, swing, file, tabs, drag-and-drop

I want Drag and Drop a file that particular file must opened in new/separate tab.I wrote the code for DragAndDrop.But It has worked when I taken Newfile then I Drag and Drop the text File from the Computer.It has copied or override the contents of a file. But,when I Drag and drop a file,It should open in a separate tab.How can I do this.Please give me suggestions.Thank you.I have post my original application.It has two classes.

Main class:

```
public class OpenDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ChangeListener{
  private ArrayList<OInternalFrame> frames = new ArrayList<OInternalFrame>();
  private OInternalFrame currentFrame;
  int i=0;
  JTabbedPane tabbedPane2;
  public OpenDemo() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                        
private void initComponents() {
    tabbedPane2=new JTabbedPane();
    this.add(tabbedPane2);
    enableDragAndDrop();
    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jMenu1.setText("File");
    open.setText("Open");
    open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(open);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    pack();
}                       

private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(OpenDemo.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.setVisible(true);
    String sts;
    if (fd.getFile() != null) {
        sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
        System.out.println(sts);
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sts));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
        String t = str.toString(); 
        OInternalFrame internalFrame = new OInternalFrame("",true,true);  
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
                i--;
                frames.remove(currentFrame);
                tp.remove(currentFrame);
            }
        });
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
        tp.addChangeListener(this);
        frames.add(internalFrame);
        currentFrame=internalFrame;

        currentFrame.setText(t);
        currentFrame.setVisible(true);
    }     
}
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
    JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) ce.getSource();
    int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    try {
        currentFrame =frames.get(index);
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new OpenDemo().setVisible(true);
    }
  });
  }
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem open;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;    
private void enableDragAndDrop() {
    OInternalFrame iFrame=new OInternalFrame("",true,true);
    DropTarget target=new DropTarget(currentFrame.textArea,new DropTargetListener(){
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
    }
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent e) {
    }
    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
    }
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
    }
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
        try {
            e.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            java.util.List list=(java.util.List)e.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            File file=(File)list.get(0);
            //JTextArea newTabTextArea=new JTextArea();
            //DropTarget target=new DropTarget(newTabTextArea,this);
            DropTarget target=new DropTarget(currentFrame.textArea,this);
            //newTabTextArea.read(new FileReader(file),null);
            currentFrame.textArea.read(new FileReader(file),null);
            //newTabTextArea.setCaretPosition(0);
            currentFrame.textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
            //tabbedPane2.add(add(newTabTextArea));
            tp.add(currentFrame.textArea);
            int tabIndex=tp.indexOfComponent(currentFrame.textArea);
            tp.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
            tp.setTitleAt(tabIndex,file.getName());
            add(tp);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
 });
}
}
```

OInternalFrame :

```
public class OInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame
{
public JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
JTabbedPane tabbedPane2;
public OInternalFrame(String title,boolean resizable,boolean closable)
{
    super(title,resizable,closable);
    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    tabbedPane2=new JTabbedPane();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    textArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
    add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(textArea);
    setVisible(true);
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
}
public void setText(String t) {
    textArea.setText(t);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
    textArea.setVisible(true);
    textArea.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: Anyone give me reply.

Comment: Consider putting in the effort to post well formatted code, and many will consider putting in the effort to read it. Please remember that we are volunteers, and if you make it more difficult for folks to understand your code and problem, many will just move on to the next question.

Comment: I edit my code.It can understand easily.Please check it once.Thank you for reply.

Comment: Anybody give suggestions,How to proceed the above task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repalce Your OpenDemo file with this code : 
   Changes are

- Added New internal frame for each Drop Event
- Added Drop event listner in main frame which was missing.
- Added Drop Listner in internal frame when it is added through Open menu item
- Added New Internal Class for DropListner instead of anonymous class to have code reuse.
- some minor chagnes
- You should Debug step by step ,and you can found these issue easily.

  ```
  public class OpenDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ChangeListener
  {
  private ArrayList<OInternalFrame> frames = new ArrayList<OInternalFrame>();
  private OInternalFrame currentFrame;
  private DropTargetListener dropListner;
  int i=0;
  JTabbedPane tabbedPane2;
  public OpenDemo() {
    initComponents();
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void initComponents() {
  dropListner=new DropTargetListener();
  currentFrame=new OInternalFrame("doc1",true,true);
  tabbedPane2=new JTabbedPane();
  this.add(tabbedPane2);
  enableDragAndDrop();
  tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
  jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
  jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
  open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
  setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  jMenu1.setText("File");
  open.setText("Open");
  open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          openActionPerformed(evt);
      }
  });
  jMenu1.add(open);
  jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
  setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
  javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
  getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
  layout.setHorizontalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
  );
  layout.setVerticalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE));
  pack();
   }

  private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(OpenDemo.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
  fd.setVisible(true);
  String sts;
  if (fd.getFile() != null) {
      sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
      System.out.println(sts);
      BufferedReader br = null;
      StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
      try {
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sts));
          String line;
          try {
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  str.append(line + "\n");
              }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      String t = str.toString();
      OInternalFrame internalFrame = new OInternalFrame("",true,true);
      i++;
      internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
      // Should file name here
      internalFrame.setName(fd.getFile());
      DropTarget target=new DropTarget(internalFrame.textArea,dropListner);
      try {
          internalFrame.setSelected(true);
      } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
              i--;
              frames.remove(currentFrame);
              tp.remove(currentFrame);
          }
      });
      tp.add(internalFrame);
      tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);
      tp.addChangeListener(this);
      frames.add(internalFrame);
      currentFrame=internalFrame;

      currentFrame.setText(t);
      currentFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
  }
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
  JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) ce.getSource();
  int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
  try {
      currentFrame =frames.get(index);
  }
  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
  }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
          if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
              javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
              break;
          }
      }
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          new OpenDemo().setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  }
   private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
   private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
   private javax.swing.JMenuItem open;
   private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
   private void enableDragAndDrop() {
   DropTarget target=new DropTarget(this,dropListner);
   }

   private class DropTargetListener implements java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener
   {
   public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
   }
   public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent e) {
   }
   public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
   }
   public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
   }
   public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
   try {
      e.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
      java.util.List list=(java.util.List)e.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
      File file=(File)list.get(0);
      OInternalFrame newOInternalFrame=new OInternalFrame(file.getName(),true,true);
      DropTarget target=new DropTarget(newOInternalFrame.textArea,dropListner);
      newOInternalFrame.textArea.read(new FileReader(file),null);
      // currentFrame.textArea.read(new FileReader(file),null);
      newOInternalFrame.textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
      // currentFrame.textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
      //tabbedPane2.add(add(newTabTextArea));
      tp.add(newOInternalFrame);
      int tabIndex=tp.indexOfComponent(newOInternalFrame);
      tp.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
      tp.setTitleAt(tabIndex,file.getName());
      add(tp);
  }
  catch(Exception ex){}
  }
  }
  }
  ```

Image:[image]

Comment: Hi,I post another question in Stack overflow.The question is "How to find out a given string in a line using java".My main theme of this one is,I take text file as input then I check every line. Whether It has given search string or not if true I want to print that line on console.Search should exact word not a sub string of another word.Please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to open file in new tab. I have added code in Method:drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) and constructor. please use according to your need , change jframe hight and width .Reply if need any help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class DragAndDropFile extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JTextArea textArea;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane2;

public DragAndDropFile() {

    //initComponents();
    textArea=new JTextArea();
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textArea);
    tabbedPane2=new JTabbedPane();
    this.add(tabbedPane2);
    enableDragAndDrop();

}

private void newFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    //tabbedPane.add(scrollPane);
}

private void enableDragAndDrop() {

        DropTarget target=new DropTarget(this,new DropTargetListener(){
        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
        }
        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent e) {
        }
        public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
        }
        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent e) {
        }
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
            try {
                e.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                java.util.List list=(java.util.List) e.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                File file=(File)list.get(0);

                JTextArea newTabTextArea=new JTextArea();
                DropTarget target=new DropTarget(newTabTextArea,this);
                newTabTextArea.read(new FileReader(file),null);
                newTabTextArea.setCaretPosition(0);
                tabbedPane2.add(newTabTextArea);
                int tabIndex=tabbedPane2.indexOfComponent(newTabTextArea);
                tabbedPane2.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
                tabbedPane2.setTitleAt(tabIndex,file.getName());


            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info :  javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DragAndDropFile.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DragAndDropFile.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DragAndDropFile.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DragAndDropFile.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new DragAndDropFile().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JMenu file;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem newFile;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried to integrate with my code. It's not working.My Application has two classes.The main class is OpenDemo.In this,check openActionPerformed() methode and stateChanged() .Second class is OInternalFrme,In this I write DragAndDrop() method and call this from class Constructor.But,It is not working.Please check it.Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your integration issue.

1. You have to create new text area each time you drap a file because you want them in separate tab so change your drop method drop  in OInternalFrame with below

   ```
   public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
   try {
       e.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
       java.util.List list=(java.util.List)e.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
       File file=(File)list.get(0);
       JTextArea newTabTextArea=new JTextArea();
       DropTarget target=new DropTarget(newTabTextArea,this);
       newTabTextArea.read(new FileReader(file),null);
       newTabTextArea.setCaretPosition(0);
       tabbedPane2.add(add(newTabTextArea));
       int tabIndex=tabbedPane2.indexOfComponent(newTabTextArea);
       tabbedPane2.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
       tabbedPane2.setTitleAt(tabIndex,file.getName());
   }
   catch(Exception ex){}
   ```

   }
2. You have not add tabbedpane2 in you frames . According to your code it look like your are planning to add in Internal frame. But i suggest to add drop listener in OpenDemo frame it will look good but depends on your requirement.add below line in initComponents method

   ```
   this.add(tabbedPane2);
   ```
3. After this it will work when you add file from menu item (first file is not visible you should work on that). then once internal frame is added you can drag and drop file you needed.

4.I suggest to have tabbedpane2 and drop listener in main frame ie openDemo and remove internal frame but depends on your design.

see screen shot.[image]

Comment: I changed my code with your code suggestions.But,it's not working.My main theme is after run the application,I drag and drop a text file it will automatically open a file.For example in my application when I click on open Menu Item it opens a file in new tab.Another case is when I open a file 

through Menu Item after I Drag and Drop a file then that particular file must be open in new tab followed by already open file.In the above code The Drap and Drop method is added in OpenDemo class. Please check it.Thank you for putting effort on my task.